# Fill info to Excel from Access with an update button VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, button

I'm trying to get info from an access DB query to an excel spreadsheet with an Update button. I've found some code that should be working but when I run it it says something about "Run error '3061'. Too less parameters given, at least 1 expected".

Here is the Code:

---

```
Sub Rektangelmedrundadehörn1_Klicka()

Sheets("Blad1").Range("A2:B500").ClearContents

    Set DB1 = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("Path to my DB")
    Set QD1 = DB1.QueryDefs("Name of my Query")
    Set RS1 = QD1.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    Sheets("Blad1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS1



    RS1.Close
    QD1.Close
    DB1.Close

End Sub
```

---

When I debug it stops at the "Set RS1" and says it's empty. Maybe I dont even have the connection with my Access columns? I've checked the names of the columns and they are the same. I have also added the references to access and DBO in excel vba.

I only using 2 columns in excel. A1, B1

Comment: Does the query require parameters?

Answer (score 1):

There is something in your query's SQL which the db engine thinks is a parameter.  I will guess your query includes a function which is available from within an Access application session, but can not be used in a query run from outside an Access session.  Possibilities include user-defined functions and many VBA functions.

Whether or not my guess was correct, there is something the db engine thinks is a parameter.  Find out what that is.

If you know how to set a temporary breakpoint, set one on the `Set QD1` line.  Otherwise, add a `Stop` statement after that line.  (Remove `Stop` after you've finished testing.)

```vb
Set QD1 = DB1.QueryDefs("Name of my Query")
Stop
```

Either approach will trigger break mode when you run the code.  And from break mode you can use the Immediate window to examine the query's `Parameters` collection.

```vb
Debug.Print QD1.Parameters.Count
```

If that tells you `Parameters.Count` is 1, you can then find out the name of that parameter.  Note the parameters collection items are numbered starting with 0.

```vb
Debug.Print QD1.Parameters(0).Name
```

Hopefully the problem will be clear once you see the name of the parameter.  If not, show us the parameter name and your query's SQL.